# Problem while setting up Cloudfront - '' Miss'' as result in result_type and x_edge_detailed result type logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently trying to create a cloudfront distribution, with an application load balancer (ALB) as an origin.
I have set up an apache Server on both my EC2 instances (which are linked to the ALB) and created two different repositories under:

```
/var/www/html/cache/index.html
/var/www/html/no_cache/index.html
```

with the two files (index.html ) referencing on which instance they are, and if they belong to the caching or non-caching setup-
After that, I tried to set up cloudfront in order to cache the files with pathpattern */cache/* (using a managed caching policy ) and not to cache the files with path pattern */no_cache/*. The default setting is set up for non-caching also.

after so many trials, I figured out that cloudfront is not caching anything. the index.html file under /cache/index.html changes instantantly when I edit it and refresh the page.

I tried to see the logs and queried them from athena:
Here I have the results:

[image]

As you can see, I always get '' Miss''  as result in result_type and x_edge_detailed result type logs. From the official AWS Docs, the interpretation of miss looks like this:
Miss – The request could not be satisfied by an object in the cache, so the server forwarded the request to the origin server and returned the result to the viewer.

Could some one tell me more about the problem? I am really confused.